# Yii select first record from table where it does not have a record in a related table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have a MySQL database with two tables:

**quiz_questions** has 2 columns:

- question_id (pk)
- question

**quiz_results**

- user_id (fk to user)
- question_id (fk to question)
- answer_id (fk to answer)

I would like to get the next question that does not have any results associated with it. In other words, get the question where the ID is not found in the results table

I figured out the raw SQL is this:

```
SELECT 
    qq.question_id, qq.question
FROM
    quiz_questions qq
LEFT JOIN 
    quiz_results qr
ON 
    qq.question_id = qr.question_id
WHERE
    isNull(qr.user_id)
ORDER BY question_id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

How can I achieve the same using models?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an answer table? You say that you have two tables in the database but answer_id seems to be a fk to an answer table.

Comment: Yes sir but it's not relevant for my current query, I just want to see questions who have results, answers just have an ID and the content of the answer.

Comment: Ok sorry, I can see now what you mean, I was got mixed up because you say "..get the question where the ID is not found in the answer table.." you might want to edit that. I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: I've been trying a few things, using relations and scopes and I think that, given the way that your db is structured, the best would be to pass the query parameters to Question::model()->find(); I couldn't find a way to do it efficiently using AR only. The data model seems a bit strange from my view point, I view a result as representing the answer that an user chooses to a question, if so, how can there be a record without a user_id, wouldn't it be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it might give you somewhere to start.

in the question model

```
    public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'results' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Result', 'question_id'),
    );
}
```

in the result model

```
    public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'question' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Question', 'question_id'),
    );
}
```

Add a static function to question

```
public static function getUnansweredQuestion() {
    $criteria = new CDBCriteria();
    $criteria->with =
        array('result'=>array(
             'select'=>false,
             'together'=>true,  // Do the join but discard the result values
        );
    );
    $criteria->addCondition('t.question_id NOT IN 
        (SELECT question_id FROM quiz_results WHERE user_id = '.
        User::model()->findByAttributes(
            array('username'=>Yii::app()->user->name))->id.')');
    $criteria->limit = 1;
    $criteria->order = 't.id ASC';

    return Question::model()->find($criteria);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does help, almost there except I need to alter the criteria so that ((result.user_id IS NULL) OR (result.user_id <> 29)) - (29 is a user ID I am testing with, it will actually be variable). When I alter the condition to the above, it still returns the row even if the user has answered. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Think I figured it out. I changed the condition to "$criteria->addCondition('t.question_id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM quiz_results WHERE user_id = 29)');" where 29 is a variable user id. This seems to do the trick. Also I changed "$criteria = new DBCriteria();" to "$criteria=new CDbCriteria;" (typo?) and also " $criteria->with(" to "$criteria->with = array(" (typo?). Your answer was very helpful, really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the corrections, they were all typos, I edited the post to reflect your corrections. I also changed the condition to use the id of the current user, recovering it from the application instance. Let me know if this code works for you, it assumes a User model with a username attribute that is used as the application's user->name attribute. If you propose a better solution I can reedit the post. Thanks again for your corrections.